# Dropdown box enabling button

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Due to company media policy I cannot paste the code. I have spent weeks surfing the net looking for the below roadblocks I have come across. As this is my first ever vba coding I'm finally stuck

1. What I have is a dropdown box with 4 options:

   One option makes button13(or button name in this case “on duty”) visible or enabled, the other 3 do nothing all.

   I have tried

   ```
   if range (“b4”) = “on duty” then
           Button13.enabled = true  and tried (name.enabled = true)
       Else
           Button13.enabled = false (name.enabled = false)
   ```
2. A different dropdown box on (sheet1) with 4 options with 2 of them I need to have them up the row above onto a different (sheet2) as this runs over a 24 hr period and I have been using the `Now date format` but need the `now date` at the `time` of the `update` on (sheet1)

All I have been able to find so far is auto update for formulas, and as this is based on the dropdown box and not in a userform.

Comment: I am not after help with any other part the code that I have already written. The help I am needing is, what the code would be. As I can not find that information

Comment: Hi Davesexcel, yes I did try that. even though I have read that buttons are not really able to be placed as hidden, and CommandButtons can be but the CommandButton was not running the macro that I set up and Buttons are. This is why im stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide Forms button if B4= "on duty"

```
Sub HideButton2()
    If Range("B4") = "on duty" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 2").Visible = False
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 2").Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Davesexcel, that was perfect. And with a little editing i have exactly what i was after. Thanks heaps